# How to serialize nested objects with related models?

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

i am really new to DRM and i have to following problem
I have three related models. Now i want to for each sensor values to the related patient. My models look like:

```
    class Sensor(models.Model):
        sensor_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
        sensor_refreshRate = models.FloatField()
        sensor_prio = models.IntegerField(choices=[
            (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), ], default='1')
        sensor_typ = models.CharField(
            max_length=200, 
            choices=[
                ('bar', 'bar'), ('pie', 'pie'), 
                ('line', 'line'), ('text', 'text'), 
            ], 
            default='bar'
        )
    
    class Patient(models.Model):
        firstName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        lastName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        age = models.IntegerField()
        doctor = models.ForeignKey(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        sensor = models.ManyToManyField(Sensor)
      
    
    class Value(models.Model):
        value_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        value = models.FloatField()
        sensor = models.ForeignKey(Sensor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now i would like to send a JSON file which looks like:

```
[
    {
        "value": 445.0,
        "sensor": "Pressure",
        "patient": 3
    },
    {
        "value": 478.0,
        "sensor": "Temperature",
        "patient": 3
    }
]
```

Now i am not sure how to serialize my JSON.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

your data models seems incomplete.
There's no link between the `Value` model and the `Patient` one.
So first I'd suggest to modify the `Value` model

```py
class Value(models.Model):
    value_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    value = models.FloatField()
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(Sensor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then you could create a queryset

```py
qs = Value.objects.filter(.....).values(
    'patient_id', 'sensor__sensor_name', 'value'
)
```

and the write your serializer

Comment: Sorry, i have forgot to mention that i want to add values to the existing patient and the existing sensor. I have added the missing link between value and patient. Now i can create a new value for a patient and a specific sensor but only for one sensor. How can i send one JSON which contains a bunch of sensors for a specific patient?